# Uniqueness of the Frechet Derivative: the role of $x \in int_X(T)$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, frechet-derivative

I'm currently trying to learn some functional analysis as a way to improve my ability to read economic theory papers. I've come across what I thought was a simple proof but on reflection I don't think I'm grasping it. I'm not a mathematician so I apologise if this question is rather trivial! My problem lies in the proof of the uniqueness of the Frechet derivative.

Here is the definition that I'm using (From Efe OK's book Real Analysis with Economic Applications).

**Definition**
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two normed linear spaces and $T$ a subset of $X$. For any $x \in int_X(T)$, a map $\Phi : T \rightarrow Y$ is said to be Frechet differentiable at $x$ if there is a continuous linear operator $D_{\Phi,x}\in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow x} \frac{\Phi(\omega)-\Phi(x)-D_{\Phi,x}(\omega-x)}{\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
The linear operator $D_{\Phi,x}$ is called the Frechet derivative of $\Phi$ at $x$.

The proof proceeds by taking any two $K,L \in \mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ that satisfy the definition of the Frechet derivative, with $D_{\Phi,x} = K$ and $D_{\Phi,x} = L$. We must then have 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow x} \frac{(K-L)(\omega-x)}{\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
The next step is where I'm confused. Since $int_X(T)$ is open, this is equivalent to saying that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{v \rightarrow \mathbf{0}} \frac{(K-L)(v)}{\left\lVert v \right\rVert} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}
The rest of the proof is reasonably straightforward. The author provides a warning in the footnotes that if $x \notin int_X(T)$ the final two displayed equations are not equivalent, and the Frechet derivative in this case is not unique.

It seems intuitively reasonable that the final two expressions are equivalent but I'm not sure how to show it. My initial thought is that, with $x$ in the boundary, it limits the directions from which one can converge to it.

Comment: From the look of it, it seems to me that when they take the "small variation" $\omega-x$ they imply the further requirement $\omega\in T$ (which is not obvious and could restrict the "directions of variation" unless $x$ is an internal point) whereas in the second equation $v$ could have any direction. I could be wrong, but this is a known source of non-uniqueness for the derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to see this using an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.
 $\Phi$ is differentiable at $x$ **iff** there exists some continuous linear $L$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $\|x-y\| < \delta$ then
$\|\Phi(y)-\Phi(x) - L(y-x) \| \le \epsilon \|y-x\|$.

Suppose $K,L$ satisfy the equation, then
$\|(K-L)(x-y)\| \le \|\Phi(y)-\Phi(x) - K(y-x) \| + \|\Phi(y)-\Phi(x) - L(y-x) \|$. Now choose $\epsilon>0$ and get some $\delta_L,\delta_K >0$
such that the above holds. Then if $\|x-y\| < \min(\delta_L,\delta_K)$ we have
$\|(K-L)(x-y)\| \le 2 \epsilon \|y-x\|$.

Since $x$ in the the interior, there is some $B(x,\eta) \subset T$ and so
for any $h \in B(0,1)$ we have
$\|(K-L) \eta h\| \le \epsilon \eta \|h\|$ or $\|(K-L) h\| \le \epsilon \|h\|$, since $(K-L)$ is linear.

In particular, $\|K-L\| \le \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary 
we have the desired result $K=L$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you go Into a bit more detail about $x$ being in the interior? I don't follow the argument at that point. It seems to me that we are introducing $\eta$ only to immediately get rid of it. How does this argument fail if $x$ is not in the interior?

Comment: Being in the interior is a sufficient condition as it guarantees that every direction is 'available' from $x$ (as long as $\|h\| < \eta$). To uniquely define the derivative it is sufficient to have a set of directions $H$ that form a basis for $X$ such that $\{x\}+H \subset T$.

Comment: An example of where it fails is  if $\Phi$ is defined on the $x$ axis on the plane. Then the derivative is only uniquely defined in the $x$ direction - you can define it arbitrarily in the $y$ direction.

Comment: I tried it from a "more topological" approach - I'd be pleased to get your opinion on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What if we take it from \begin{equation}
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow x} \frac{(K-L)(\omega-x)}{\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert} = \mathbf{0}
\end{equation}

1. It follows that ${(K-L)(\omega-x))} =\mathbf{0}$ for any $\omega \in T$ because

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\omega \rightarrow x} \frac{(K-L)(\omega-x)}{\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert} = \lim_{\omega \rightarrow x} {(K-L)(u)} = {(K-L)(u)} =\mathbf{0}
\end{equation}  Where $ u = \frac{(\omega-x)} {\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert}$ is a non-zero vector (of unit length).
(Since $K - L$ is continuous it is everywhere defined (even if $\Phi$ isn't) so $u$ is in its domain even if it isn't in the domain of $\Phi$ )

Hence $(K - L){\left\lVert \omega-x \right\rVert}u = {(K-L)(\omega-x))} = 0$

2. Since $x \in T$ and $T$ is open then there is an open ball $B_r(x)$
   around $x$.
   So for any non-zero vector $v \in X$ take $w = x + r.v/2.||v||$ and then $||w - x|| < r$ i.e. $w \in B_r(x)$ and $v = \alpha (w - x) $ where $\alpha = 2.||v||/r$
   Since ${(K-L)(\omega-x))} =\mathbf{0}$ it follows that ${(K-L)(v)} =\mathbf{0}$ for all $v \in X$ and therefore that $K = L$